# TYPO3 IRRE 1:n delete child records doesn't work

Tags: typo3

I'm new to TYPO3, I don't have much of experience. I'm working with the official documentation. TYPO3 version 7.6 LTS.

I have created 1:n relation. Almost everything works fine, child items are saved and loaded without any problem. I have a problem with delete, though. When I delete parent entity, its children are **not** removed, which is a real pain.

Here's my TCA configuration for both tables (I have removed irrelevant columns):

`tx_myext_domain_model_item` parent table:

```
<?php

$ll = 'LLL:EXT:myext/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:';

return [
    'ctrl' => [
        'title' => $ll . 'basket.item',
        'label' => 'title',
        'tstamp' => 'updated_at',
        'crdate' => 'created_at',
        'cruser_id' => 'user_id'
    ],
    'interface' => [
        'showRecordFieldList' => ''
    ],
    'columns' => [
        'pid' => [
            'label' => $ll . 'pid',
            'config' => [
                'type' => 'passthrough',
            ]
        ],
        // ...
        'documents' => [
            'label' => $ll . 'item.documents',
            'config' => [
                'readOnly' => 1,
                'type' => 'inline',
                'foreign_table' => 'tx_myext_domain_model_document',
                'foreign_field' => 'item_id',
                'behaviour' => [
                    'enableCascadingDelete' => 1,
                ]
            ],
        ]
    ]
];
```

`tx_myext_domain_model_document` child table:

```
<?php

$ll = 'LLL:EXT:myext/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:';

return [
    'ctrl' => [
        'title' => $ll . 'document',
        'label' => 'item_id',
        'tstamp' => 'updated_at',
        'crdate' => 'created_at',
    ],
    'interface' => [
        'showRecordFieldList' => ''
    ],
    'columns' => [
        'pid' => [
            'label' => $ll . 'pid',
            'config' => [
                'type' => 'passthrough',
            ]
        ],     
        // ...   
        'item_id' => [
            'label' => $ll . 'item.id',
            'config' => [
                'type' => 'input',
                'size' => '10',
                'eval' => 'int',
            ],
        ],
    ],
];
```

Anyone has an idea of what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks for help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are telling the TCA to look up the field 'item_id' for the relation

```
'foreign_field' => 'item_id',
```

but this field is used for the id of the item. 
In this field typo3 should store the uid from the parent element.
Try to set the 'item_id' field on passthrough and create an new element and check in the DB if in the field ist stored the uid from the parent. If this is the case then cascadeDelete should work. 
enableCascadingDelete is per default on :)

edit:
if you do the stuff inside your code and you use extbase repositorys to delete the objects you need to add @cascade remove to the property documents in your item model. Is described in the docs under:

https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/ExtbaseFluidBook/5-Domain/2-implementing-the-domain-model.html#implementing-relationships-between-domain-objects

Comment: The thing is that adding documents to items only through the code. I can see that the `documents` field from the parent table counter is behaving correctly. I don't want this to be editable through admin panel.

Comment: if you use extbase repositorys to delete the objects in your code you need to add @cascade remove to the property documents in your item model.

Is described her in the docs:
https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/ExtbaseFluidBook/5-Domain/2-implementing-the-domain-model.html

Comment: Yes! Thank you @Xippo! I was missing the `@cascade` annotation! I don't know how I missed it. Please update your question with this suggestion and I'll accept it :)